# Fast splitting of list of files in chunks of the same size (memory)

Tags: linux, memory, filesystems, rsync

See title. Assume I have the following list of files and relatives sizes:

```
cat list_of_files.txt:

1243 001.txt
124  002.txt
4132 003.txt
3000 004.txt
```

I want to be able to split into multiple chunks having the same size (on disk), i.e, for N=2 it would be:

```
for N=2 

list_A.txt: 001.txt 002.txt 004.txt
list B.txt: 003.txt

N=3:

list_A.txt: 001.txt 002.txt
list_B.txt: 003.txt
list_C.txt: 004.tx

etc..
```

What would be the most efficient way of computing those chunks?

FYI: I want to be able to parallelize rsync, if you have any better way of doing it (rsyncing each file individually won't do it), I'd really appreciate suggestions.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671496/how-to-split-a-list-of-items-into-equal-partitions-according-to-the-items-weigh

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic combinatorial, it's called "partition problem".

You can make a C program to compute that, dont worry about the algorithm, there are many libraries available online. I've just found [this](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/c_src/subset/subset.html), in case you need to run it often you'll have to write the C prog to search in directories and grab the file sizes.

If you want to use it just once or in a more messy way, you can put all filenames and sizes in a file name ALL_FILES, grab the filenames and sizes in a C array and compute partitions using the library.

Dont like C? Plenty of other options, just search "partition problem *ur_fav_language*"